# Can configuration of Log4j be changed on the fly?

Tags: java, log4j

I need to know if configuration changes on log4j like changing the logging level from INFO to DEBUG etc ... can/do effect the application on the fly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It might, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch%28java.lang.String,%20long%29.
This requires changing your log4j initialization code since default initialization does not watch for changes (follow the code in line 127 in http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.java to see it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You may programmatically add/remove appenders, change logging levels etc. And yes, they take effect on the fly.

Comment: ... but changing the logging config file won't have any effect, unless you have some extra infrastructure that notices the file and reruns the logger configuration process.

Comment: maybe I'm misreading, but that doesn't appear to be what he's asking

Comment: The point is that the question just says "on the fly" without saying how he intends to implement the on the fly change.  It is possible that the OP is thinking of modifying the properties file to make this happen.  (And it appears my comment could have triggered Oded Peer to tell us that it is possible to do this in HIS answer.  That's a good outcome IMO.)

Answer (score 1):

It does not support this behaviour by default but seems to be configurable with the api. Another solution could be Logback. It is the successor to Log4j and does support automatic reloading of configuration files out of the box. See http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html for more info about this and other reasons to prefer logback over log4j.

Comment: Also, Log4j version 2  also supports dynamic config changes with a 30-second listener configured in the log4j.properties itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Log4j version 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) has a monitorInterval arg option for the log4j.properties file.